# Python: Insert the base64 image into SVG file

Tags: python-3.x, base64

The context is I have created a .svg file using graphviz for a flow chart.
I want to insert the other logo picture(can be .png or other format) into the .svg file and then distribute it.
I have the base64 code for this logo. However, I don't know how to insert it with the .svg file.
I tried the solution as https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2020/12/how-to-embed-base64-images-in-svg, and it doesnt' work.

The step I followed(Use google logo as an example):
**Step 1:Get the base64 encoding - Successful**

```
import base64
img = r"C:\data\cwd\googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"
with open(img, 'rb') as image:
    image_read = image.read()
    image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_read)
```

**Step 2: Copy the above base 64 string(without the b') as text and edit the .svg file using text editor i.e. notepad++**
Below one works fine on my PC:

```
<image xlink:href="c:\data\cwd\googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png" width="160px" height="22px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" x="121.5" y="-480"/>
```

replace it to:

```
<image href="data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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"/>
```

I have checked the output of step 1, starts with iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN and ends with VAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC, to make sure I have copied the full string.

**Step 3: Save the .svg file, and open it using google chrome but no logo show up**

Can you please advise where you see as incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

`image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_read)`

Should perhaps be:

`image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_read).decode('ascii')`

Here's how I accomplished inserting a PNG into a SVG (using Python to do all the work).

Note: *I created an SVG with a placeholder PNG, then edited the SVG file and replaced the existing `xlink:href="..."` data with `xlink:href="[PNGREPLACE]"`. If you open it with Inkscape, the image will display as broken*.

```
import base64
import io

def replace_png_inside_svg(svg_location, png_location):
    prepend_str = "data:image/png;base64,"
    encoded_str = base64.b64encode(open(png_location, "rb").read()).decode('ascii')
    
    data_tuples = [
        ("[PNGREPLACE]", prepend_str + encoded_str)
    ]
    # Make a copy of the "svg_location" file to preserve it as a template if needed...
    changeSVGtextPlaceholders(svg_location, data_tuples)
    # The SVG located at svg_location has now been updated with new information.

def changeSVGtextPlaceholders(svg_output_file, data_tuple):
    character_encoding = "utf-8"
    template_svg_file = io.open(svg_file, 'r', encoding=character_encoding)
    template_svg_file_lines = template_svg_file.readlines()
    new_content = ""
    for line in template_svg_file_lines:
        for check_str_tuple in tuple_lookup_and_replace_list:
            check_str = check_str_tuple[0]
            replace_str = check_str_tuple[1]
            if (check_str in line):
                line = line.replace(check_str, replace_str)
                if (debug_output):
                    print ("\tReplacing [" + check_str + "] with [" + replace_str + "]")
        new_content += line

    template_svg_file.close()

    new_SVG_file = io.open(svg_file, 'w', encoding=character_encoding)
    new_SVG_file.write(new_content)
    new_SVG_file.close()

replace_png_inside_svg(r"c:\data\cwd\my_cool_vector.svg", r"c:\data\cwd\googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png")
```